# Sending HTML Mail with jeronimo mail implementation

Tags: html, jakarta-mail, geronimo

When I am trying to send a mail as HTML using geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.2.jar it arrives as plain text. All solutions I found on Google suggest to exclude jeronimo and use SUN's JavaMail implementation. Here for example:
[How to properly send mail javax.mail 1.4 with HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297165/how-to-properly-send-mail-javax-mail-1-4-with-html-code/27404356#27404356)

I cannot do that because it's licensed under a CDDL which is deemed not acceptable by our company policies (legal department).

Is there any way to make it working using *geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec*? Surely this is considered a bug which might get fixed or has a workaround?

I have tried the latest available version 1.8.4.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to upgrade the commons-mail API to 1.5 which fixed this problem